# Does calling the same HttpRequestMethod wait for the existing one to finish

Tags: c#, asynchronous, httpwebrequest

I have a workagent agents that runs every 60 seconds checking processing tables for new work, each 60 seconds if new work is available. During processing the agent uses a static TraceHelper class for logging purpose. At the point of writing to the log file I also send a WebRequest to an external API to ship the log entry to a Logstash.

The Webrequest essentially sends off a json object for each Writeline. obviously for logging purposes, order is important so my question is, even though I am only calling one POST HttpWebRequest this is happening hundreds of times a minute. Should I be worried about syncing issues? Could there be a potential that the second Writeline requests gets called and processed by the HttpWebRequest before the first Writeline has a chance to send? Or am I looking into wrong?

Note: below is semi pseudo code

Say I have the below

```
Tracehelper.Writeline("foo")
Tracehelper.Writeline("baa");


static Tracehelper(){}


public static void Writeline(string msg)
{
    File.WriteToFile(msg);
    WebProcessHelper.SendLog(msg);
}



static WebProcessHelper() {}

public static void SendLog(string msg)
{
   SendHttpRequest(msg);
}
```

Is there a potential that "baa" is sent ahead of "foo"?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what classes you are actually using for the web request, but I'll assume its the default async ones and answer it based on that.If you are using something else, the answer may vary.

Yes and no. The requests will all be fired by the client in order. However if you are doing this hundreds of times per second, you may have the messages accepted by the server on the other end not in the same order since they may stack up and exceed the handling capacity of the server. Totally depends on the number of connections, and the server software used.

All that said, making hundreds of HTTP calls a second is an awful idea. If you need to log, use a logging framework that lets you buffer and batch up the logging into a request every second or two. This will greatly save you bandwidth, add scalability, and relieve CPU load on the server you are logging to.

I can heartily recommend either nLog or the Semantic Application Logging Block from MS. Have used both, and they are both really flexible and handle load well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I guess I didn't have a lot of room or desire to put up the full project. The method that eventually sends the WebRequest does batch it up before sending. about 100 batches per cycle. I guess the point i wanted to make is, even if i did batch it up..I wanted to know about the order that the request would send them in which I have the answer now. I will now look into the async webreqeust framework in .net 4.5

Answer (score -1):

It's safe to assume that there's the possibility, especially if you're dealing with multiple threads running at once. A safe option would be to set up a separate thread with a `BlockingCollection` or something that simply pulls strings out of the `BlockingCollection` and sends them off to logstash.

That way you could have it such that anyone can write something to the `BlockingCollection`, and they'll all get sent to the remote server in the right order.

Comment: There was no mention of threading, only async which is not the same. And logging should always be batched up, especially if logging remotely.